# python script gets killed by test for stdout

Tags: python-3.x, cgi

I'm writing a CGI script that is supposed to send data to a user until they disconnect, then run logging tasks afterwards.

THE PROBLEM: Instead of break executing and the logging getting completed when the client disconnects (detected by inability to write to the stdout buffer), the script ends or is killed (I cannot find any logs anywhere for how this exit is occurring)

Here is a snippet of the code:

```
        for block in r.iter_content(262144):
            if stopRecord == True:
                r.close()
            if not block:
                break
            if not sys.stdout.buffer.write(block): #The code fails here after a client disconnects
                break
        cacheTemp.close()

        ####write data to other logs and exit gracefully####
```

I have tried using "except:" as well as "except SystemExit:" but to no avail. Has anyone been able to solve this problem? (It is for a CGI script which is supposed to log when the client terminates their connection)

UPDATE: I have now tried using signal to interrupt the kill process in the script, which also didn't work. Where can I see an error log? I know exactly which line fails and under which conditions, but there is no error log or anything like I would get if I ran a script which failed in a terminal.

Answer (score 0):

When you say it kills the program, you mean the main python process exits - and not by some thrown exception? That's kinda weird. A workaround might be to have the task run in a separate `Thread` or `process`, and then monitor that until it dies and subsequently execute the second task.

Comment: I should have been clearer. I said program when I should have said script. The weirdest thing is I have no idea why or how the script is being killed on client disconnect. As it is running as CGI, I can't get a look at any exit log for it. The whole idea behind this loop was to continually send data to the client until they disconnected, then do a graceful exit, saving all relevant data to the log.

I would definitely settle for at least seeing a log to know what is happening.